# Not able to print from specific software (Xerox 6280)

Tags: laser-printer, print-drivers

I've just installed a Xerox 6280 laser printer on my Windows 7 Pro machine, through USB. I've encountered no issue during the install.

I'm able to print from Acrobat and IE, but NOT able to print from Word or Excel or Thunderbird emails.

I've also shared this printer and printed from 2 other PCs on my network, so I don't think it's a printer malfucntion.

An other clue is that I'm NOT able to print the Test page from the printer's properties dialogue box.

I've tried to uninstall/reinstall the printer, but same result...

Anyone has a hypothesis? Could it be a printer driver issue? Or a USB driver issue?

Comment: You have install all firmware and software updates for the printer?

Comment: Hmmm... Did not check for the firmware. I'll try that out.

Comment: Did a firmware update, but that did not change anything... Anyother guess guys?